# Allow page break for many aligned equations (ConTeXt)

Tags: math-mode, equations, page-breaking, context

When there are many aligned equations so that they cannot fit the rest of the current page, page break is not allowed, and they always start at a new page, giving a lot of blank lines.
How to allow the page break?

I found [this post](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2006/018107.html) in the mailing list, but the question was not answered, and it is old.

```
\starttext

Is it possible to let aligned equations break, so that the following equations do not start at new pages?
\placeformula
\startformula
\startalign
   \dorecurse{50}
   {\NC E =\NC m c^2 \NR}
\stopalign
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

Comment: Try using `\startsplitformula…\stopsplitformula` instead of `\startformula…\stopformula` (I don't know whether it works with `\placeformula` though).

Comment: @TeXnician Well, thanks for pointing out duplicate! It's frustrating why I often fail to find the existent question. I really have searched relevant keywords, but I guess the word "context" just sinks among the sea of its literal usage.

Comment: Maybe the biggest problem of our beloved ConTeXt system is only lack of a identifiable name : (

Comment: I agree. Try searching with `inurl:contextgarden` or `inurl:tex.stackexchange`. That might help :)